# Should I put a comma between this list of 2 facts?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, numbers

Let A denote the phrase

> A: John showed that x is a positive number,

and let B be the phrase

> B: Kim showed that x is a multiple of 2.

I want to say that a fact follows from A and B. My current attempt is

> C: It follows from the fact(s) that (i) John showed that x is a positive number **and** (ii) Kim showed that x is a multiple of 2 that (conclusion).

1) Is it poor etiquette (say, for an academic paper) to use (i) and (ii), and should there be a comma before **and**? Without (i) and (ii), a comma seems appropriate to separate the facts, but unnecessary since it is a list of length 2. Should I include **s** in **facts**? I think so, but it sounds awkward.

2) I'm open to other ways of expressing C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write

> John showed that x is a positive number, and Kim showed that x is a
>   multiple of 2. It follows that ...

and exclude *from the fact(s)* and *(i),(ii)* altogether because it sounds awkward. The comma before *and* may be [included or omitted (when the two facts are short)](http://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/7847-commas-and-conjunctions-joining-independent-clauses/).

Comment: Thanks, that does sound better. Can you provide a link for the last fact you stated?